# Setting LayoutParams programmatically

Tags: android

I want to set my LinearLayout's parameters after all of the views' parameters are calculated.

I am trying to set LinearLayout's height related to the parent view's height. And parent view's height is calculated according to its `layout_weight`, so I get the height by `getMeasuredHeight();`

My code :

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

  super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
  RelativeLayout lay = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.alt);
  LinearLayout bar = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.barLay);

  int layH = lay.getMeasuredHeight();
  int barH = layH / 4;
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) bar.getLayoutParams();
  params.height = barH;
  bar.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Eclipse Debugger stops the program at this line;

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) bar.getLayoutParams();
```

I can't find what could be the problem? Am I doing something wrong to set params?

Comment: control bar is inside what layout type?

Comment: The layout that I want to set the params is Linear, and its parent is Relative.  I will try changing the relativeLayout to LinearLayout and write the result here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of LayoutParams are actually set by the parent of the view, so bar.getLayoutParams() should be returning an object of type `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`. With an explicit cast to `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` I'd expect your logcat to contain a line like this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams
```

Changing it to this should do the trick:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) bar.getLayoutParams();
```

or, since height is in the base class, don't cast it at all:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = bar.getLayoutParams();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) bar.getLayoutParams();
```

to this

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) bar.getLayoutParams();
```

Comment: post the logcat? that will help

Comment: Logcat has 6000lines I dont know what part to post :(

Answer (score 0):

After @LocHa asked me the type of the layouts, I try changing the parent layout's type to LinearLayout which was RelativeLayout, and finally it worked for me.

Comment: That is why you need to know its parent layout type. Since its parent is RelativeLayout. So you must cast the layoutParams to RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.